# How to call out a list of cells from other sheets base on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am a university student and I am trying to make a cover page which can copy a list from other sheet base on an input from one cell.

For example, in the excel, I have 3 sheets: Daiquiri, Manhattan and GinTonic. And I want to open a new sheet, and by typing in the cocktail name (say: Manhattan) in cell A1, it will automatically appear the ingredient from that sheet underneath.

The difficulty is, if the ingredient numbers for that cocktail are different from each sheet, how can I code it so it can generate all the item according to the relative sheet?

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? [Edit] your post to show the code you have tried, and the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks Olly, I have currently coded as follow, but when it runs, it showed run time error '1004': application define or object define error, can you please help to check where the problem is?